# Hide folder using Apache HTTPD

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, httpd

I'm using Apache HTTPD server and I have a 3 static folders on my root, namely "css", "js" and "images". How do I rewrite it so that it can't be seen from the outside world? I know they're static resources and should be seen by the world but I have some configurations in place where they are replaced by CDN urls on my site.

So what I want to do is make requests to these paths a 404. I currently have this code:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?(css|js|images)/
 RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ - [G]
```

G for gone, and I've tried F for forbidden too. But all I want is a 404. The second thing is, if you type www.domain.com/css, it redirects/resolves to www.domain.com/css/ and gives the gone message. I simply dont want to give the inquisitive user a clue that the folders are there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why the very specific need for a 404?  There's really no reason that a 403 shouldn't work.

I'd say just block them without needing rewrites (in location blocks, directory blocks, or htaccess, take your pick)...

```
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
```

but if you really do need a 404, and you can't just delete the files, then rewrite the paths to a nonexistent file, I guess.  Really though, there's no reason to do this and you're over-complicating your config.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(css|js|images)/
RewriteRule ^.*$ /nonexistentfile.html
```

Comment: This answers the other half of my question. Im going to give the correct answer to Shane Madden because Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams has 15.8k rep already. But both answers are correct. Thanks you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Make the trailing slash optional.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?(css|js|images)/?
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for, but the other half of my question (404) was answered by Shane Madden by rewriting the request to a non-existent file. Thanks to both you guys!